# Java Array Index

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, grid

So I am trying to make an index from an array to go around the grid of question marks I already have. I am trying to get it to output the number of each column and each row of the grid but I can't get it to properly go around the grid. Does anyone have an idea of how I may do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class H4_Minesweeper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Game Description and rules
        System.out.println("Minesweeper is a very straightforward game, the rules are simple.");
        System.out.println("Uncover a mine (x), and the game ends. Uncover an empty square (o), and you keep playing.");
        System.out.println("A question mark (?) will represent tiles you have not uncovered yet.");
        System.out.println("Uncover a number, and it tells you how many mines lay hidden in the eight surrounding squares.");
        System.out.println("To enter which tile you would like to uncover, please enter the column number, then row number of that tile.");
        System.out.println("\n\n");

        Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Index of the grid
        int[] column = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        for (int counter = 0; counter<column.length;counter++){
            System.out.print(counter);
        }

        //9x9 grid output
        String[][] board = new String [9][9];
        for (int r = 0; r<board.length;r++){
            for (int c = 0; c <board.length;c++){
                {   
                }
                board [r][c] ="?";

                System.out.print("[" + board[r][c] + "]");
                }

                System.out.println();
        }
        //User input for column & row
        String move = userin.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are printing the column numbers, but not the row numbers. I suggest this change:

```
    System.out.print("  ");
    int[] column = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for (int counter = 0; counter<column.length;counter++){
        System.out.print(counter); // print column number
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(""); // empty row

    //9x9 grid output
    String[][] board = new String [9][9];
    for (int r = 0; r<board.length;r++){
        System.out.print(r+" "); // print row number
        for (int c = 0; c <board.length;c++){

            board [r][c] ="?";

            System.out.print(board[r][c]); // print cell value
            }

            System.out.println("");
    }
```

This should print

```
  012345678

0 ?????????
1 ?????????
2 ?????????
3 ?????????
4 ?????????
5 ?????????
6 ?????????
7 ?????????
8 ?????????
```

Hopefully, that's what you meant. If you still want to print the `?` as `[?]`, you'll have to add extra spaces between the column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`Arrays.fill(Object[], Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) and [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29). Something like,

```
// 9x9 grid output
String[][] board = new String[9][9];
for (String[] arr : board) {
    Arrays.fill(arr, "?");
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board));
```